# Domain redirected you too many times

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache web server.

I would like to setup a reverse proxy to access a local application running on port 9090.

Here is my apache configuration :

```
ProxyRequests Off

NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA

# Redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/example.com/public_html"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/example.com/public_html"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9090/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RequestHeader unset Origin
</VirtualHost>
```

The configuration is not working. I'm getting the error : example.com redirected you too many times

The server is hosted at an EC2 AWS instance.

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks.

Comment: That usually means you're in a redirect loop that's unresolvable. See if this helps -  https://serverfault.com/a/920598/494284

Comment: Did you try a different browser, or did you clear the cache?

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana yes. Actually it turns out that [VirtualHost *:443] is completely ignored. Do you have any ideas please ?

Comment: Add `Listen 443` to your httpd.conf and restart Apache. Also, check out your other question too, I've answered

Comment: I do have Listen 443 but it's still not working unfortunately.